# Do any mobs dive after you?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If a mob is chasing you, and the only way to get you is by diving under water, will they dive under water?

I know they swim to get you, but I've never seen them diving.

Answer (score 10):

No, hostile mobs can't navigate water very well, and they won't specifically dive for you.

Either they automatically float to the top at all times — most of them do — or they sink to the bottom. Iron Golems will for example will not even chase you into water because they can't swim at all and will sink like a rock.

Comment: Define "can't swim", they won't enter water?  They sink?  They glitch out and don't move if they touch water?

Comment: @NickT They just sink and can't get out. I'm still trying to determine whether they will actually chase you into water.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the mobs' behavior in water is the equivalent of you constantly holding space bar. i.e. they are always trying to swim to the surface.

(although some dont, also n.b. iron golems don't swim and also don't drown)

Comment: This is what makes a few really simple grinders work.

Answer (score 0):

As of the 1.8 Release, Guardians dive after you

Comment: This doesn't seem to be up to date on the [Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Guardian#Combat), do you have a source?